# Is there a way to disable these additional Cloud Function resources from loading?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Sorry, I'm just getting started with Cloud Functions so excuse me if this doesn't make sense.

I noticed when watching the ['Node.js apps on Firebase Hosting'](https://youtu.be/LOeioOKUKI8?t=463) video that each load was only returning the document in question. However I set up my cloud function and noticed that it is also loading some other resources like a favicon?

My cloud function is making a call to an external api and then returning it to the user. All I need is the json body from the response. Do I need these other resources?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser is always going to request favicon.ico.  That's how it determines what icon to show for the site in the title.  It's harmless.  There might be some way to disable that for whatever browser you're using, but I don't think it's worthwhile to worry about it.